# exact param search match with keycloak REST Api

Tags: keycloak

I'm using Keycloak REST Api to get users with query param

```
Get users Returns a list of users, filtered according to query parameters
GET /{realm}/users
```

with query param `?username=admin`, but for this query param value I also get similar results like `awadmin` username etc. How to get Exact account with admin username

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with older version of docs-api. In latest 12 there is explicitly mentioned

> A String contained in username, or the complete username, if param
> "exact" is true
> https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/12.0/rest-api/index.html

Comment: in my experience (Keycloak 9) the exact param has not effect on the results, it's always a "contains" search...Doh! It seams this feature was added in v11.